# Syntax for set_fact

Tags: ansible

I have my Ansible inventory file as:

```
[dev_web:children]
dev_www
dev_auto

[dev_www]
web01_dev    ansible_host=web01-dev.company.com
web02_dev    ansible_host=web02-dev.company.com
web03_dev    ansible_host=web03-dev.company.com

[dev_auto]
auto_dev     ansible_host=auto-dev.company.com
```

Ansible playbook "/deploys/patch.yml" as:

```
- name: patch
  hosts: "{{ configs_target | default('test_servers') }}"
  serial: 1
  vars:
    slack_token: 'slack-token'
    slack_channel: 'slack-channel'
  roles:
    - patch
```

Main Ansible playbook file "/deploys/roles/patch/tasks/main.yml” as:

```
---
- name: Include vars of patch.yml
  include_vars:
    file: backend_vars.yml
    name: web_servers

- name: set needed facts
  set_fact:
    backend_name: "{{ [cache_mgmt][configs_target]['backend_name'] }}"
```

Variable file “/deploys/roles/patch/vars/backend_vars.yml” as:

```
cache_mgmt:
  dev_web:
    backend_name: www_http_be
    backend_hosts: dev_www
  dit_web:
    backend_name: www_http_be
    backend_hosts: dit_www
```

The run command I execute is:

> ansible-playbook /deploys/patch.yml -e '{"configs_target":"dev_web"}'

When I run the playbook, I expect the value of variable to be `backend_name: www_http_be`. But, it fails with below error.

```
TASK [patch : set needed facts] *****************************************************************************************
fatal: [web01_dev]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'dev_web'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/deploys/roles/patch/tasks/main.yml': line , column , but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: set needed facts\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I believe the issue is with the syntax for set_fact. If that is true, what should be the correct form in this case?

Comment: See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-complex-variable-data => `cache_mgmt[configs_target]['backend_name']` or `cache_mgmt[configs_target].backend_name`

Comment: @Zeitounator, Thanks for the help but none of them worked. I still get the variable `backend_name` not loading with the value `www_http_be`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/6f5d02c1539b1edd0002d2e20c00113d

Answer (score 0):

Since the vars are being called from a variable file, we'll have to mention the assigned name as well. The correct syntax is `"{{ web_servers['cache_mgmt'][configs_target]['backend_name'] }}"`